# SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns with new value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables.

Table #1:

```
+----+------+-----+
| ID | Y    | AGE | 
+----+------+-----+
|  1 | 2022  |  a | 
|  1 | 2022  |  b | 
|  3 | 2021  |  a | 
|  4 | 2021  |  a | 
|  4 | 2021  |  b | 
|  4 | 2021  |  c | 
|  7 | 2021  |  a |
|  7 | 2022  |  b |
+----+-------+----+
```

Table #2:

```
+----+------+-----------+
| ID | num  | something | 
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | 10  |  a1221     | 
|  3 | 30  |  a4342     | 
|  4 | 40  |  bdssd     | 
|  7 | 70  |  asdsds    |
+----+-----+------------+
```

and I would like to merge them into this result set:

```
+----+-------+-----+
| ID | Y     | num | 
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | 2022  |  10 |  
|  3 | 2021  |  30 | 
|  4 | 2021  |  40 | 
|  7 | 2021  |  70 |
|  7 | 2022  |  70 |
+----+-------+-----+
```

That means I would like take unique pairs of `T1.ID` and `T1.Y` ignoring column `AGE` and them `INNER JOIN` resulting table with `T2` on `T1.ID = T2.ID`.

I know I can do this in steps as

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ID, Y 
    FROM T1
    GROUP BY ID, Y 
)
SELECT cte.ID, cte.Y, T2.num
FROM cte 
INNER JOIN T2 ON cte.ID = T2.ID
```

but is there any better way without creating a temporary table? Because simple

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Y, T2.num
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

will result with duplicates that comes from `T1.AGE` even tho I'm not using it

Comment: Please tag only a **single** RDBMS!

Comment: Temporary table? Using a cte doesn't mean you have to get a temportaty table. the optimizer might decide something else.

Comment: Seems like a classic "`TOP 1` (or alternative rowset limiting operator) in each group" problem.

Comment: @jarlh maybe not "temporary table" but still it is like a "helper", that may be not efficient

Comment: Trust the optimizer!

Comment: Did you try SELECT DISTINCT ... in your last query?

Comment: @forpas seems like it may do the work, thanks

Comment: @Larnu can u extend ur answer?

Comment: Not without knowing the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: @Larnu sorry, I did not know there are major differences between them - I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use views for this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.view1
AS
SELECT
  ID
 ,Y
FROM T1
GROUP BY ID
        ,Y
GO
```

And call it wherever needed like tables:

```
SELECT v1.ID, v1.Y, T2.num
FROM view1 v1
INNER JOIN T2 ON v1.ID = T2.ID
```